# jQuery Mobile app not not displaying elements correctly

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

SO...my app has a few issues, but I am DESPERATE to solve this one first. Any thoughts and suggestions are welcomed. Here is the app:

http://pocketfacilitator.com

Here's the issue - (NOTE, Firefox doesn't even allow this issue to fire, so maybe try Chrome or Safari, or a mobile browser):
From the home page, click on Portables > List All Portables. Now, click on any of the PLUS signs on the right (or two or three, doesn't matter). Now, check the "TODAY" page (in the very bottom nav bar). It will display the list of games you clicked on, but the way they are displayed is totally jacked. BUT...if you RELOAD the page (or just click the red CLEAR button), and repeat the process, it looks normal. What have I done wrong?

If you dare: in Firefox, it won't even let me add an activity -- clicking on the "+" button yield NO effect.

I appreciate any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `refresh()` method on your listview after you dynamically add items

```
$(this).parent().appendTo('#todaylist');
$('#todaylist').listview('refresh');
```

See [Updating lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)

> If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the **refresh()**
>   method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are
>   added.

Comment: Oh, that's excellent! Is that why I'm getting the console message: "cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' " ?

Comment: Thank you, by the way. That led me to a solution. Turns out I didn't need `refresh()` - I had a bad function, but your suggestion got me to the answer.  Cheers for that!

Comment: Good. If it was of any help  please, consider to [accept/up vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. Happy coding.